# batchfile to check directory for new file

Tags: batch-file

In the below `batch` file, I am trying to check a directory, which will only contain text files (no sub-directories), for new files added. The script below executes but always displays `New file detected`. Eventually I will add it to the startup menu so that the directory is checked upon login. There probably is a better way, but I am not too familiar with `batchfiles`. Thank you :).

**Batch**

```
@echo off
:START
cls
set /a Old = 0
set /a New = 0
echo Checking for new annotated files...
for /f "tokens=*" %%P IN ('dir "path/to/directory" /A /b') do (set /a Old += 1)
set Old
echo Checking for new files..
for /f "tokens=*" %%P IN ('dir "path/to/directory" /A /b') do (set /a New += 1)
set New
goto COMPARE

:COMPARE
if %New% gtr %Old% goto NEWF (
goto NEWF
)
else (
goto OLDF
)

:NEWF
echo New File Detected.
echo.
pause

:OLDF
echo Nothing New.
echo.
pause
```

Comment: Is it like this?
https://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created

Comment: It is sort of what i am trying to do, but trying to pin it to a user login to automate it. However, i am not sure what i am doing is right, since i am comparing file count in the directory is there a way to store the value of the previous days count in that directory, then compare it to the count today? Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking to see if any new files where created in a directory, you can use `xcopy` to check for files before `x` date. Since you did not post a date or time on your post, I will assume it's current date.

You do not need to check for files younger then the date given as you don't need to compare them. All you need to do is check if the files returned as "New" are less then 1. This can be done with the following:

```
if %New% gtr 0 (goto NEWF) else (goto OLDF)
```

If you wish to search sub-directoies in the future, you can use the `/S` switch with *xcopy* `/L /S /D:`.

For the pause statement's you had, you would have ran into problem's if the script was to continue (As it had no where to go). To fix this you can simply exit the script using `goto :eof`. Use `echo(` instead of `echo.`

```
@ECHO OFF
set /a New = 0

:: Gather & edit the date for xcopy.
SET CurrentDate=%date%
SET CurrentDate=%CurrentDate:/=-%
SET CurrentDate=%CurrentDate:* =% 

:: Check for files created today.
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('xcopy "path/to/directory" /L /I /D:%CurrentDate%') do (set /a New+=1)
set /a New-=1

goto COMPARE

:COMPARE
if %New% gtr 0 (goto NEWF) else (goto OLDF)

:NEWF
echo New File Detected.
echo(
pause
goto :eof

:OLDF
echo Nothing New.
echo(
pause
goto :eof
```

Comment: I already know people are going to yell at me for the use of %date%. I'm aware of the issues relating that.

Comment: Thank you both, I appreciate the help :).

Answer (score 1):

store the value in a file old.txt. If this file exist get the value inside and loop true all .txt files and test the value. Here the comented code :

```
@echo off&cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Default value

set "New=0"
set "old=0"

:: If exist old.txt get the real value 

if exist old.txt set /p Old=<old.txt


echo Checking for new annotated files...

::Count of the txt files

for /f %%$ IN ('dir *.txt') do set /a New+=1

:: Update the value of the old.txt for the next check

echo !New!>old.txt

:: Testing the 2 values

if !New! gtr %Old% (goto NEWF) else (goto OLDF)

:NEWF
echo New File Detected.
echo.
pause
exit/b

:OLDF
echo Nothing New.
echo.
pause
exit/b
```